# How to stop thread.sleep from stopping entire JFrame

Tags: java, multithreading, jframe, sleep

This is probably a quick and newbie fix but I am desperate at the moment. When I use a Thread.sleep, it stops the whole JFrame, is there a quick fix for this?

Sample code

```
public  void delay() throws InterruptedException {
    //Construct to create a delay.  
    Thread.sleep (30);
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the delay? And what method calls `delay()`?

Comment: Try with interrupt.
Thread t = new Thread();
t.sleep(30);
t.interrupt();

Comment: What is it you're trying to do? Do **not** call `sleep()` on the Swing event dispatch thread!

Comment: Swing GUI needs to run in its own thread. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html

Comment: I would call this method to a method with a JFrame in it, and the JFrame will pause, which is what should not be happening.

Comment: ... ? _"call this method to a method with a JFrame in it"_ ? A method cannot "have a JFrame in it".  What do you mean?

Comment: I'm creating a JFrame in the method. When I call the method, the JFrame should show up, but the thread.sleep delays the entire JFrame.

Comment: Take a look at [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)

Comment: Your method delay() should be called in another thread, not the JFrame (UI) thread. otherwise, UI will be blocked.

Answer (score 1):

If its just a delay you want to implement, `javax.swing.Timer` is a good option. You could use it like this:

```
    public void delay(){
        Timer timer = new Timer(30, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                //do stuff after delay
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }
```

This could probably be improved on if you showed more code. You can find a tutorial [HERE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).